# how do i add a moving image onto a HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, animation, canvas, web, html5-canvas

I need to have a moving image on my html5 canvas which will be an animation without having to click a button to start it. 
can anyone help me?

thank you

Comment: How do you want it to animate? (ping, pong, bounce, random, ...). Please share the code you have so far with us. If possible please also include a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some commented code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8wY6K/

It works like this:

- create an animation loop using requestAnimationFrame: http://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/
- inside that loop: increment where you want the image to be positioned next.
- Clear the canvas and redraw the image at the new location.
- repeat, repeat, repeat.

The code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: white; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas related variables 
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // define a circular path
    // for our image to travel
    var cx=50;
    var cy=50;
    var radius=40;

    // a variable to hold the current degree of rotation
    var degreeAngle=0;

    // load an image
    // when the image is fully loaded, call start()
    // start() will start the animation loop
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/ship.jpg";
    function start(){
        animate();
    }

    // this is an animation loop
    // using requestAnimationFrame
    function animate(){

        // request that this animate() function be called again
        // this creates an animation loop
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        // clear the canvas

        // calculate the new position of the image
        // this example just rotates it around a centerpoint   
        degreeAngle+=1;
        var radianAngle=degreeAngle*Math.PI/180;
        var x=cx+radius*Math.cos(radianAngle);
        var y=cy+radius*Math.sin(radianAngle);

        // clear the canvas 
        // and draw the image at its new position
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);    

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="test">Test</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```